# Concise way to remove elements from list by index in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I have a list of characters and list of indexes

```
myList = ['a','b','c','d']
toRemove = [0,2]
```

and I'd like to get this in one operation

```
myList = ['b','d']
```

I could do this but is there is a way to do it faster?

```
toRemove.reverse()
for i in toRemove:
    myList.pop(i)
```

Comment: The example implementation you give is incorrect, or perhaps your spec is. That algorithm removes the item at index 0, then removes the item which was moved to index 2 due to the removal (that is, `'d'`).

Comment: I used `toRemove.reverse` so the first element to be removed is on index 2 and I do then remove the element on index 0. This works only when the `toRemove` list is sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to, you could use `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

myList = ['a','b','c','d']
toRemove = [0,2]

new_list = np.delete(myList, toRemove)
```

Result:

```
>>> new_list
array(['b', 'd'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Note that `new_list` is a `numpy` `array`.

Comment: Don't you think Numpy is a bit of overkill just for a simple 'delete array' problem?

Comment: Maybe the OP is using `numpy` already and the lists in question are millions of elements?  If so it is probably the fastest answer.

Comment: @SuperDisk, I think `numpy` way is pretty convenient, and could be useful. Of course this task is easy without 'numpy', but `numpy` option is worth mentioning.

Comment: I have numpy, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Youcha No offense, but you should probably specify what modules you are using next time :)

Answer (score 5):

Concise answer

```
>>> myList = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> toRemove = [0,2]
>>> 
>>> [v for i, v in enumerate(myList) if i not in toRemove]
['b', 'd']
>>>
```

Comment: Make `toRemove` a set and this is actually a very good algorithm. It's `O(m)` instead of `O(n * m)` where `n = len(toRemove); m = len(myList)` as it does not repeatedly copy half of the array each time it removes an item.

Comment: Making `toRemove` a `set` is probably a good idea but depends on how long `toRemove` and `myList` is as to whether it will be an improvement.  I didn't write that originally as I was going for concise!

Answer (score 5):

You could use a list comprehension as other answers have suggested, but to make it truly faster I would suggest using a `set` for the set of indices you want removed.

```
>>> myList = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> toRemove = set([0,2])
>>> [x for i,x in enumerate(myList) if i not in toRemove]
['b', 'd']
```

Checking every element in myList against every element in toRemove is O(n*m) (where n is the length of myList and m is the length of toRemove). If you use a `set`, checking for membership is O(1), so the whole procedure becomes O(n). Keep in mind though, the difference in speed will not be noticeable unless toRemove is really big (say more than a thousand).

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
>>>[myList[x] for x in range(len(myList)) if not x in [0,2]]
['b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to do it for you.

```
def removethese(list, *args):
    for arg in args:
        del list[arg]
```

Then do

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
removethese(mylist, 0, 1, 4)
```

mylist now is ['c', 'd']

Comment: This implementation is as incorrect as OP's (assuming, again, that the spec is correct).